# SQL query result table to an HTML table for email

Tags: query, table

please help me to figure this out. I need to send sql query results as html table. The challenge is that columns in this table are dynamic (most recent 5 dates). How can I replace literal column names in CAST function with actual dynamic column names? Just replacing with variable name (ex. Activity -> @header1) does not do the magic.

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX),
                  @header1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @header2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @header3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
                  @header4 NVARCHAR(MAX), @header5 NVARCHAR(MAX), @header6 NVARCHAR(MAX), @test NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @header1 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =1);
set @header2 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =2);
set @header3 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =3);
set @header4 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =4);
set @header5 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =5);
set @header6 = (SELECT column_name FROM [sample_db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] where TABLE_NAME = 'sample_table' AND ORDINAL_POSITION =6);
set @test = "sample_table" + '.' + @header1;
SET @tableHTML =   
    N'<H1>Sample Report</H1>' +  
    N'<table border="1">' +  
    N'<tr><th>'  + @header1 + '</th>' +
    N'<th>' + @header2 + '</th>' +
    N'<th>' + @header3 + '</th>' +
    N'<th>' + @header4 + '</th>' +
    N'<th>' + @header5 + '</th>'+
    N'<th>' + @header6 + '</th></tr>' +   
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = Activity,       '',  
                    td = December_3, '',  
                    td = December_2, '',  
                    td = December_1, '',  
                    td = December_30, '',  
                    td = December_29  
              FROM [sample_db].[dbo].[sample_table] 
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )  ;  
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='111C SQL DBA',
  @recipients='tester@mail.com',
  @subject='Sample Subject',
  @body = @tableHTML,  
   @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: To provide _dynamic column names_ you'll need to build and execute a _dynamic SQL statement_.

Comment: Are you possibly looking for something like `SELECT @header1 AS Activity, @header2 AS December_3,…`? This replaces the names as stored in the database with strings of your choice. If you are looking for something else, please, provide a sample of your expected output.

Comment: I want to produce the same result using variables, not current column names when I build HTML table:                                                                                   
     `CAST ( ( SELECT td = @header1,       '',  
                    td = @header2, '',  
                    td = @header3, '',  
                    td = @header4, '',  
                    td = @header5, '',  
                    td = @header6  
              FROM [sample_db].[dbo].[sample_table] 
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )`

Comment: However, this approach does not work. It prints column names for each row instead of actual values.

Comment: I ended up creating a function which would generate html table with dynamic column names, then emailed.